# The variable inside the setInterval function is not incrementing

Tags: javascript

I am trying to run a JavaScript payload with the test url. The payload contains the following script. The script is supposed to run function2 when the timeOutOfFocus>=3 but when i check the console, the timer never increments when the tab is out of focus. I am just trying to understand why ? I have attached the console output as well. Thank you for help !!

```js
// Initialize variables
let timeOutOfFocus = 0; // To track how long the tab has been out of focus
let timer; // Timer variable for interval

// Function to do something when the timer is timed out
function function2() {

  // do something
}

// Event listener for visibility change
document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', function() {
  // If the tab becomes hidden (out of focus)
  if (document.hidden) {
    console.log('Tab is out of focus'); // Display a message
    timer = setInterval(() => {
      timeOutOfFocus++; // Increment the time out of focus
      console.log(`Out of focus for: ${timeOutOfFocus} seconds`); // Display the time out of focus
      console.log(`Timer value: ${timer}`); // Display the timer value

      // If the tab has been out of focus for 3 seconds
      if (timeOutOfFocus >= 3) {
        function2(); // Call the  function2 function     
        clearInterval(timer); // Clear the timer
      }
    }, 1000); // Run every 1000 milliseconds (1 second)
  } else {
    console.log('Tab is in focus'); // Display a message
    clearInterval(timer); // Clear the timer
    timeOutOfFocus = 0; // Reset the time out of focus counter
  }
});
```

[image]

Comment: It works as expected for me.

Comment: @Barmar is the function2 being called after 3 seconds of tab being out of focus ?

Comment: `function2()` doesn't do anything so it's impossible to tell. But it stops printing "Out of fucus" when it gets to 3 seconds.

Comment: how are you running this script? On your local machine? I am running it on some test website with the following url 

https://testwebsite.com/search?q=<script> --above script-- </script>

Comment: I just clicked on "Run code snippet" above, then minimized the SO window.

Comment: you are right, i am getting the expected result as well here. So something on that test website. hmm